# freeRTOS API derefrences null pointer

Tags: pointers, null, dereference

I am new to freeRTOS, I am trying to notify a task from an ISR using freeRTOS xTaskNotifyFromISR() API, the code works fine, but after some time when this function is called and control reaches to below function it, at line pxList->uxNumberOfItems causes hardFault/BusFault because pxList is null.
I am wondering what can make pxList null.
I am using coperative scheduling and trying to run task using xTaskDelayUntil and taskYIELD APIs.
Can any one help me to trace the issue and fix?

```
 UBaseType_t uxListRemove( ListItem_t * const pxItemToRemove )
{
/* The list item knows which list it is in.  Obtain the list from the list
 * item. */
    List_t * const pxList = pxItemToRemove->pxContainer;

    pxItemToRemove->pxNext->pxPrevious = pxItemToRemove->pxPrevious;
    pxItemToRemove->pxPrevious->pxNext = pxItemToRemove->pxNext;

    /* Only used during decision coverage testing. */
    mtCOVERAGE_TEST_DELAY();

    /* Make sure the index is left pointing to a valid item. */
    if( pxList->pxIndex == pxItemToRemove )
    {
        pxList->pxIndex = pxItemToRemove->pxPrevious;
    }
    else
    {
        mtCOVERAGE_TEST_MARKER();
    }

    pxItemToRemove->pxContainer = NULL;
    ( pxList->uxNumberOfItems )--;

    return pxList->uxNumberOfItems;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it happens at the END of the function, and not at the beginning?  That would only be possible if the stack were overwritten, because it has already dereferenced `pxList`  several times.